# How to enable the Boot Splash Screen?

Tags: boot, bootloader

After hitting enter from GRUB, the screen displays a blinking cursor. How can I enable the loading screen, so that the boot splash screen displays instead of a blinking cursor??

Comment: Which graphic card do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

or have a look at this page (in spanish): http://lavidalinux.com.ar/2010/05/como-arreglar-plymouth-en-ubuntu-10-04.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it occurs, maybe you disabled it before.
[here](http://twitteling.com/2010/03/how-to-disable-splash-screen-ubuntu-karmic/) there is a explanation to disable it, so you can do the opposite.

But if you have a nvidia or ati video card that could be the problem. I have an ati card and Boot Splash Screen doesnt work for me neither

Comment: me have no more than Intel GMA, and didn't disabled it, that was my only issue from Lucid until I upgraded my Notebook to Maverick