# "Can not display this video mode" error during boot, followed by empty desktop

Tags: 11.04, resolution, monitor

On my computer, I replaced windows XP with Ubuntu 11.04. When I start up my computer, I get the message 'Can not display this video mode - optimal resolution 1280 60Hz', in a black screen. After a few minutes, I can login. After this, there appears a colored screen with only a mouse cursus, and I can't do any more!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds similar to a [problem I have](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54880/plymouth-and-grub-do-not-show-at-all) with my desktop. Perhaps you can try looking at some of the answers there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a message from your monitor, not your computer.
Open `/etc/default/grub` with gedit (root privileges required) and set `GRUB_GFXMODE` to `1280x800` (or `1280x1024` it's not widescreen), and save the file. After that, open a terminal and run `update-grub2` with root privileges.

So, in a nutshell:

1. `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Replace `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` (or whatever resolution is default, I don't remember exactly) by `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800` (or `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024` if it's not widescreen).
3. Save the file.
4. Open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub2`.